# How to increase size of edges arrow in sigma js?

Tags: sigma.js, linkurious

How to increase size of edges arrow in sigmajs?
I have this snippet of code.

```
s = new sigma({
graph: g,
container: 'network-graph',
renderer: {
    container: document.getElementById('network-graph'),
    type: 'canvas'
},
settings: {
    maxNodeSize: 16,
    minNodeSize: 45,
    minEdgeSize: 5,
    maxEdgeSize: 5,
    minArrowSize: 25
}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On every sigma edge, there is a property `size`. If you put an higger number, this will increase the edge.

Answer (score 4):

Add the attribute `size` when the edges of `g` are been created!

Example:

```
g.edges.push({
    id: 'myID',
    source: 'mySource',
    target: 'myTarget',
    size: 2, //here put a value that you want
    color: '#ccc',
    type:'arrow'
  });
```

Comment: Same issue here